# Volume of Solid of Revolution (Disk/Washer)

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

> Using disks or washers, find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $x=y−y^2$ and $x=0$ about the y-axis.

Comment: Please show how you proceeded at this time..

Comment: The upper bound of the y axis is not given. So I attempted to find the highest point of the graph which was 0.25.

Comment: How'd you get that, show it @mathguy

Comment: Since it is bounded by x= 0, the graph of x = y-y^2 is a small curve from 0 to 1 where it peaks (I think) at 0.25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection between the curves $x=y-y^2$ and $x=0$ is obtained by considering the equation $$0=y-y^2.$$ Solving the equation, we get $y=0$ or $y=1$. The points of intersection are $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$. The graph of the required region is given below:

[image]
If we rotate the horizontal strip about the $y$-axis, a disk is obtained whose volume is given by
$$dV=\pi x^2dy=\pi(y-y^2)^2dy=\pi(y^2-2y^3+y^4)dy.$$
Hence, the required volume of the solid generated is 
$$V=\int_0^1 dV=\int_0^1\pi(y^2-2y^3+y^4)dy=\pi\bigg[\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{2}+\frac{y^5}{5}\bigg]_{0}^1=\pi\bigg[\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}\bigg]=\frac{\pi}{30}.$$